# Check user write bteween 18 and 108

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to controller user write between 18 and 108 , i mean user can't put less than 18 and greater 108 .
here is the fiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/npfmvd7k/1/)

```
$scope.check = function(){
        var userInput = 18>108;
        if(!userInput){
            alert('wrong');
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your check function you could parse the value of the `check1` scope variable and compare whether it is within the specified range.

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.check1 = '';
    $scope.check = function() {
        var userInput = parseInt($scope.check1);
        if (isNaN(userInput) || userInput < 18 || userInput > 108) {
            alert('wrong');
        }        
    }
});
```

Also you probably want to perform this check when the user focuses out from the input field because right now you have subscribed to the change event which is uber annoying as every time the user types a character in the input field your alert will blow into his face:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="check1" name="number" ng-blur="check()" />
```

And here's the [`updated fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/npfmvd7k/2/).